# .cpp vs .h and where should I put function definitions

Tags: c++, function, header, definition

I've been writing in C++ lately and I'm getting confused with `.cpp` vs `.h` — when to use them and what should go in them. I've been reading that you should put function definitions in a separate `.cpp` file, and headers should be used for declarations, but how do I use the separate `.cpp` file?  Do I `#include` it or what? I'm looking for clarification on `.h` and `.cpp` and what should go where and how to include separate `.cpp` files.

Comment: do you mean normal functions or templates?

Comment: See also [C++ code in header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583255/c-code-in-header-files/), and [Splitting code into headers/source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584856/splitting-code-into-headers-source-files), and [Why have header files and `.cpp` files in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .h file for function prototype and data type **declarations** and also for pre-processor directives, and .cpp files for **definitions**. For example, `test.h` might be look like

```
#define CONSTANT 123 // pre-processor directive
void myfunction(char* str);
```

and your `test.cpp` might look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc char **argv)
{
   myfunction("Hello World");
   return 0;
}

void myfunction (char* str)
{
   printf("%s and constant %d", str, CONSTANT);
   return;
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention `inline`-functions (both implicit and explicit) and `template`s.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the class declaration goes into the (.h) header file, and the implementation goes in the .cpp file.

You include the header file in the cpp file, so all the functions will be recognized, and you should remember to use #ifndef in the header file to avoid errors (includes loops)