# Compiling a simple header with inline methods

Tags: c++, header, compilation

I have a base class `Student`, and an inheriting class `StudentAtA`.

I define `StudentAtA` inside `StudentAtA.h`, and it overides some of the methods of `Student`.

For example, if `Student` has:

```
string returnUni() 
{
 return NULL;
};
```

Then I define inside  `StudentAtA.h` an overriding method:

```
string returnUni() 
{
 return "A";
};
```

Since all the methods in `StudentAtA` are short, they're all implemented in the header file (I didn't create a `StudentAtA.cpp` file).

Now I have a `Driver.cpp` file which uses `StudentAtA`, and contains a main function. This is the executor.

Is it possible to compile `Driver` without having `StudentAtA.cpp` (just using the header)?

Comment: as long as your compiler can find the definition for your methods it's happy. However it's not recommended to put the method bodys inside the header file.

Comment: Even if the methods are 1-2 lines long? (I'm new to c\c++ and aren't familiar with the standards)

Comment: yes even then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955288/3060253   this guy summed up the reasons

Comment: @Glandy The discussion behind that link is, fortunately, a bit more balanced than your summary. There’s nothing absolutely wrong with method bodies in header files, it’s a balance between tighter coupling and giving the compiler more options for optimization. Obviously, the method listed above should be `virtual`, and in that case, there’s probably no reason to have it in a header, since it will hardly ever be eligible for inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes possible. Just make sure you include StudentAtA.h in your Driver.cpp